# Duplicate class/entity mapping <ClassName> in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

**EDIT: Added HBM mapping at the end of the post.**

I have a rather large class library, with inheritance involved. I'm using Fluent NHibernate to map the classes to MS SQL 2008 to host this in Azure.

I'm fairly sure the mappings are correct. We use a Discriminator Value to differentiate the classes on column (not on table). However, whenever I try to generate the mappings, I get an error that one of the class/entity is a duplicate.

```
Duplicate class/entity mapping FolkeLib.MMOBash.Bash
```

This happens here:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.Dialect("NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect")
                .ConnectionString(c => 
                    c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("FolkeConnString"))
                .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => 
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Account>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => 
                new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            .Diagnostics(diag => diag.Enable().OutputToConsole())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

The class hierarchy is something like this

- Message

  - Comment
  - ForumMessage

    - Article

      - Image

        - Bash

Bash inherits from Image, which Inherits from Article, and so on. They all have a different discriminator value. Message mappings are defined like this:

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>
{
    MessageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("MessageType").SqlType("int32");
        Map(x => x.CreationDate).Index("ArticleCreationDate");
        Map(x => x.ModificationDate);
        Map(x => x.LastChildCreationDate);
        References(x => x.Author);
        References(x => x.RootMessage).Nullable(); ;
        References(x => x.ParentMessage).Nullable(); ;
    }
}
```

(there are more properties but they are irrelevant I think). Note that RootMessage and ParentMessages are themselves of the type "Message." Could this be the root cause?

Bash mappings are like this:

```
public class BashMap : SubclassMap<Bash>
{
    BashMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(5);
        Map(x => x.Game);
        Map(x => x.Language);
        References(x => x.ApprovedBy);
    }
}
```

I have spent hours on this and I have no idea why I get a Duplicate class/entity mapping error.

**EDIT: Troubleshooting update.**

Following suggestions below I added this bit of code:

```
public ActionResult Zogzog()
    {
        List<string> types = new List<string>();
        foreach (var module in typeof(Account).Assembly.GetModules())
        {
            foreach (var type in module.GetTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(IMappingProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {
                    types.Add(type.ToString());
                }                    
            }   
        }
        ViewBag.Types = types;
        return View();
    }
```

The output of the view is this:

> FolkeLib.Calendar.EventRoleMap
>
> FolkeLib.Calendar.LocationMap
>
> FolkeLib.Calendar.RegistrationMap
>
> FolkeLib.Calendar.RoleMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.AccountMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.AccountBanMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.CommunityMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.ContactEntryMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.ContactTypeMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.ForumMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.ReadMessageMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.RssFeedMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.SkinMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.GroupMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.LanguageMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.MenuMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.MenuItemMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.MessageMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.PollMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.PollAnswerMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.PollVoteMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.QuoteMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.MessageReportMap
>
> FolkeLib.Game.CharacterMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.RssChannelMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.SiteMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.SiteApplicationModuleMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.StaticTextMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.TagMap
>
> FolkeLib.Domain.VoteMap

I don't seem to have duplicates, however none of the children of Message seem to appear. I'm not sure if that is normal (they are of type SubclassMap, what is shown here is of type ClassMap) or not but this was asked in the comments.

**EDIT**: This is the Message.hbm.xml file generated by Fluent. As we can see, some classes (Bash, Article, ...) are shown several time as subclasses, sometimes with different discriminator values!

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="FolkeLib.Domain.Message, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Message`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="MessageType" sql-type="int32" />
    </discriminator>
    <property name="CreationDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="CreationDate" index="ArticleCreationDate" />
    </property>
    <property name="ModificationDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="ModificationDate" />
    </property>
    <property name="LastChildCreationDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="LastChildCreationDate" />
    </property>
    <property name="Text" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Text" />
    </property>
    <property name="Locked" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Locked" />
    </property>
    <property name="Score" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Score" />
    </property>
    <property name="Hidden" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Hidden" />
    </property>
    <property name="Deleted" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Deleted" />
    </property>
    <property name="AuthorIp" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="AuthorIp" />
    </property>
    <property name="PublicationDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="PublicationDate" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Account, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Author">
      <column name="Author_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Account, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Locker">
      <column name="Locker_id" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Message, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="RootMessage">
      <column name="RootMessage_id" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Message, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="ParentMessage">
      <column name="ParentMessage_id" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Site, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Site">
      <column name="Site_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Forum, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Forum">
      <column name="Forum_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Account, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="DeletedBy">
      <column name="DeletedBy_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <subclass name="FolkeLib.Domain.Comment, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="2" />
    <subclass name="FolkeLib.Domain.ForumMessage, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="3">
      <property name="Title" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Title" />
      </property>
      <subclass name="FolkeLib.Calendar.Event, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="6">
        <bag lazy="true" name="RoleSet" table="EventEventRole">
          <key>
            <column name="Event_id" />
          </key>
          <many-to-many class="FolkeLib.Calendar.EventRole, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
            <column name="EventRole_id" />
          </many-to-many>
        </bag>
        <property name="Duration" type="System.TimeSpan, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="Duration" />
        </property>
        <property name="RecurringDays" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="RecurringDays" />
        </property>
        <property name="FirstTime" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="FirstTime" />
        </property>
        <property name="LastTime" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="LastTime" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Calendar.Location, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Location">
          <column name="Location_id" />
        </many-to-one>
      </subclass>
      <subclass name="FolkeLib.Domain.Article, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="1">
        <subclass name="FolkeLib.Domain.Image, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="1">
          <property name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Name" />
          </property>
          <property name="Extension" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Extension" />
          </property>
          <property name="Public" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Public" />
          </property>
          <property name="ForAdults" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="ForAdults" />
          </property>
          <subclass name="FolkeLib.MMOBash.Bash, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="5">
            <property name="Game" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
              <column name="Game" />
            </property>
            <property name="Language" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
              <column name="Language" />
            </property>
            <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Account, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="ApprovedBy">
              <column name="ApprovedBy_id" />
            </many-to-one>
          </subclass>
        </subclass>
      </subclass>
      <subclass name="FolkeLib.Domain.Article, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="4">
        <bag name="TagSet" table="TagToArticle">
          <key>
            <column name="Article_id" />
          </key>
          <many-to-many class="FolkeLib.Domain.Tag, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
            <column name="Tag_id" />
          </many-to-many>
        </bag>
        <bag name="ImageSet" table="ImageToArticle">
          <key>
            <column name="Article_id" />
          </key>
          <many-to-many class="FolkeLib.Domain.Image, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
            <column name="Image_id" />
          </many-to-many>
        </bag>
        <property name="ExtraText" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="ExtraText" />
        </property>
        <subclass name="FolkeLib.Domain.Image, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="1">
          <property name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Name" />
          </property>
          <property name="Extension" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Extension" />
          </property>
          <property name="Public" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Public" />
          </property>
          <property name="ForAdults" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="ForAdults" />
          </property>
          <subclass name="FolkeLib.MMOBash.Bash, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" discriminator-value="5">
            <property name="Game" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
              <column name="Game" />
            </property>
            <property name="Language" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
              <column name="Language" />
            </property>
            <many-to-one class="FolkeLib.Domain.Account, FolkeLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="ApprovedBy">
              <column name="ApprovedBy_id" />
            </many-to-one>
          </subclass>
        </subclass>
      </subclass>
    </subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: what mapping/table do you see when commenting out BashMap?

Comment: If I comment out BashMap, then Fluent complains about ImageMap. If I comment out ImageMap, Fluent complains about Article. Etc..

Comment: can you enumerate all classes of Account's assembly and print out all classnames which are `typeof(IMappingProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type)` to see if the mappings are duplicated somehow?

Comment: I have edited the OP with the code you suggested, @Firo.

Comment: you  are right. Subclassmaps are of type `IIndeterminateSubclassMappingProvider`. Another unlikely cause could be that two subclasses inherit from `SubclassMap<Bash>` and since they have the same properties it doesnt give compilererrors

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are no classes that inherit from Bash.

Comment: I've changed the code so that Fluent will generate the mappings and it's kind of nasty. Some subclasses show several time, with different (and wrong) discriminator values.

Comment: I have also had problems with FNH and inheritance, if the inheritance got deep.  (However, I was using automapping, and the symptoms were the opposite - instead of duplicates, deep classes were not being mapped at all).  Eventually had to dive into the FNH source and do a patch, which was not fun, but solved my problem. One of the things I noticed was that some of the classes seemed to be mapped multiple times, and there was logic to work around this. When I submitted a pull request to GitHub, James Gregory commented that there were problems with that part of the codebase.

Comment: I've submitted my issue on his repository, maybe he'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody found the reason. There was an error in the mappings of another class:

This was the issue:

```
public class ArticleListMap : SubclassMap<Article>
{
   ArticleListMap()
   {
      DiscriminatorValue(1);
   }
}

public class ArticleMap : SubclassMap<Article>
{
   ArticleMap()
   {
      DiscriminatorValue(4);
      Map(x => x.ExtraText);
      HasManyToMany(x => x.TagSet);
      HasManyToMany(x => x.ImageSet);
   }
}
```

Instead of inheriting ArticleListMap from `SubclassMap<ArticleList>` I was inheriting from `SubclassMap<Article>` (which was a typing mistake). Since they have different discriminators but inherit from the same class there was, indeed, a duplicate mappings than then "propagated" to the children classes.

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction, Error had nothing to do with the class raised, but a different class higher up in the architecture which I'd changed the inheritance on and forgotten to update the mapping to `SubclassMap`

Comment: Yep, I briefly talked with one of the FNH devs and he said this is probably a feature they need to work on.